# Incorporating MySQL with Java/Eclipse on OSX

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, macos

I'm going a little crazy trying to figure everything I need to get this running. The tutorial I'm reading says to install the JDK, MySql server and MySql client.  I installed sever (at least I think i did), but i can't seem to find the client anywhere.  Can I get a little guidance please?  I'm trying to follow a tutorial that shows how ot incorporate mysql with eclipse.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL server comes with a command line client.  There are also GUI clients for MySQL such as PHPAdmin and MySQL Workbench.  Does the tutorial give you any clue as to the details of this client they are talking about?

Comment: @Don.  Thanks.  The tutorial I started with is http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/ I know I have the server installed and running.  And I gather from what you're saying that the client is by default run on the command line unless I download a GUI for the client.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the client is just called mysql and is run from the command line, just make sure the MySQL bin directory is in your path.  I looked at that tutorial, it's using the command line client.

Comment: @Don. I'm using the terminal command line and I notice he specifically says that the tutorial was tested on Ubuntu Linux.  Are the command lines in terminal different than the ones he is using because i can't seem to even create the .java file using his command lines

Comment: As far as the MySQL client goes, the syntax is the same.  I read further down in the tutorial and it mixes MySQL client commands with native OS commands.  For example the JRE and the Java compiler get run from the OS command line, but SQL commands get run from within MySQL client.  To create the .java files you will need to run a local editor.  WHen you see a "mysql> " in the tutorial this command is run from within MySQL client, if not it appears to be a native OS command so run from an OS shell.

Comment: @Don. Towards the top, I'm trying to decipher what he's doing.  he says `If you want to compile the examples from the command line, go to the site http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and download the MySQL connector for the Java language.

$ javac zetcode/Version.java
$ java -cp .:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar zetcode/Version
5.5.9`

That first line looks like he's creating the .java file.  But why?  The package hasn't even been created yet.  when I type `javac Version.java` it says `javac: file not found: Version.java`

Comment: Did you download the zetcode sources and go to that directory before running javac?

Comment: @Don. I ran the .dmg installer for the JDK.  I moved my workspace to my dropbox folder.  Maybe I should have specified a different install location for the JDK?  I did not download anything from zetcode. I assumed his paths were interchangeable with my own paths.  I've followed his tutorials int he past and never had to download zetcode sources.

Comment: The error message indicates it's looking for a java source file named zetcode/Version.java.  The tutorial has the source included so you could create the file by cut and paste then run the javac command again.  The zetcode directory is the Java package name.

Comment: So I have to already have created the project and package in my IDE (Eclipse)?

Comment: Yes the javac is the Java compiler so it is expecting the source file to be there.  That's why it says not found.  If you have Eclipse running you can create the .java source in your workspace and project and let Eclipse compile it for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51387/discussion-between-don-and-stuart-kuredjian)